# How can one describe the accuracy of a Runge-Kutta method?

Tags: matlab, numerical-analysis, ode, error-estimation, runge-kutta

I am solving a nonlinear ODE with a regular singularity using MATLAB ODE45 or ODE113.

I am wondering what precision and accuracy they have and what one can say about the numerical error. The idea would be to write a statement like

> "The solution was found by means of ODE45 which has an accuracy
>   of...".

Comment: ODE113 does not use a Runge-Kutta method.

Comment: I know that but thanks for pointing that out. I could have written that it uses Adams-Bashforth-Moulton but the question about the accuracy would still apply to it...

Comment: What I meant to imply is that the title of your question does not accurately reflect the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RK4* method is a fourth-order method, meaning that the local truncation error is on the order of $O(h^5)$, while the total accumulated error is order $O(h^4)$.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. Do you think that for a second order ODE with nonlinearity and regular singularity Runge-Kutta yields trustworthy results?

Comment: NB: Dmitry's statement is valid only in the asymptotic convergence regime $h \rightarrow 0$ (i.e., when $h$ is sufficiently small).

Comment: In the most widely accepted terminology, the local truncation error of this method is actually $O(h^4)$.  The *one-step error* is $O(h^5)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`ODE45`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) uses adaptive stepping, you might want to mention the error tolerance (`RelTol` and `AbsTol`) used. There is some information in the [`odeset` documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#zmw57dd0e525830).